# Global variable modification on switch / case in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

Im new for php, I would like to know how can I update global variables for each method that Im invoking:

(pay attention to the   `global $text1`  variable pls, specially from this line-->  `$this->welcome($to, false);`   :

In the method welcome I try update the global  `$text1`  variable in this way :

```
$GLOBALS['text1'] = "lorum ipsum";
```

I would like to use the new value of $text1 ("lorum ipsum") on the  switch case 1 :

```
case '1': { 
    $this->client->sendChatMessage($to, date('d.m.Y H:i:s'). "valor de val". $GLOBALS['text1'] ); 
    break;
}
```

but, It is always return empty.

Can you please advise me how can get the modified value of $text1  in the switch / statement case 1?

Thanks

```
class ultraMsgChatBot
{
    var $client;
    var $text1 ;
    var $randMsg;

    public function __construct($ultramsg_token, $instance_id)
    {
        global $license;
        global $randMsg;      
        global $text1 ;

        require_once('ultra.class.php'); 
        
        require_once('ultra-dictionary.php');

        $ultramsgDictionary = new ultramsgDictionary();
        $this->client = new UltraMsg\WhatsAppApi($ultramsg_token, $instance_id);
   
        ////////  Processing incoming messages
        if (isset($decoded['data'])) {
            $message = $decoded['data'];
            $text = $this->convert($message['body']);

            
            if (!$message['fromMe']) {
                $to = $message['from'];
                $val = mb_strtolower($text, 'UTF-8');
                switch ($val) {
                    case in_array($val, $ultramsgDictionary->welcomeIntent()): {
                        $randMsg = $ultramsgDictionary->welcomeResponses();
                      
                        $this->welcome($to, false);
                  
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    case '1': {
                        $this->client->sendChatMessage($to, date('d.m.Y H:i:s'). "valor de val". $GLOBALS['text1'] );
  
                        break;
                    }
                }

                public function welcome($to, $noWelcome = false)
                {
                    $welcomeStr = "hola"
                    $this->client->sendChatMessage(
                        $to,
                        $welcomeStr 
                    );
      
                    $GLOBALS['text1'] = "lorum ipsum";  
                }

            }
```

Comment: Why are you using globals at all? Pass them in as an argument to your constructor, or use a setter, or even a public property. You appear to be loading a class in the constructor: load it externally to your class. Your `welcome()` function looks like it ought to be a method in your class, but it's declared outside the class. There's more, but too much for a comment.

Comment: You've got a lot of problems here. This code won't run, but if you fixed it to the point where it will, `$GLOBALS['text1']` is always empty because the only place you ever set a value for it is in the `welcome` method, which is only called in the first case statement. So unless the first statement runs, then the second, you never set a value in it. You really don't need to do anything with globals here at all, except maybe for the `$license`, which I don't see used anywhere, but should probably be a constructor argument..

Comment: If you look at your code now after I've added some proper code indention, it's completely all over the place and would throw syntax errors. You need to keep track of  your open `{` and close `}`.